# Why in my links collection contain empty object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, collections, view, controllers

Why I get collection object with nil parameters, that I didn't create advisedly?

***routes.rb***:

```
devise_for :users
  root to: "posts#index"

  resources :posts do
    resources :comments, only: [:new, :create]

    resources  :images do
      resources :comments, only: [:new, :create]
    end

    resources  :links do
      resources :comments, only: [:new, :create]
    end

  end
```

***post_controller:***

```
 class PostsController < ApplicationController

      before_filter :authenticate_user!, :only => [:new, :create]

      def index
        @posts = Post.all
      end

      def show
        @post = Post.find(params[:id])
      end

      def new
        @post = Post.new
      end

      def create
        @post = Post.new(post_params)

        respond_to do |format|
          if @post.save
            format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully   created.' }
            format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @post }
          else
            format.html { render :new }
            format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
      end
```

***links_controller:***

```
class LinksController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_link, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @links = Link.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @link = @post.links.new
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @link = @post.links.new(link_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @link.save
        format.html { redirect_to post_path(@post,@link), notice: 'Link was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @link }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @link.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

I get **@post.links** in */posts/:id*, I have written on views/posts/show.html.erb:

```
<%= @post.links %>
```

and I have got collection with empty parameters:

```
#<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy 
[#<Link id: nil, url: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, post_id: 6>]
```

**Why?**

Comment: I guess there are a few things that I'd like to see in addition to what you've got up there. What are the params being passed into your controller action? You can get these from your logs. Also what version of Rails are you using? If it's 4 or higher I'm not seeing where you're whitelisting/blacklisting params.

Comment: I use 4 version

Answer (score 0):

So far as I can tell you don't define `link_params` anywhere in the in the controller. you would need to do something like this

```
link_params = params[:link_params] #assuming there is nested params under the name :link_params
```

Comment: Where I should write it, and how can I use this link_params?

Comment: I had gone from work to home, when you answer me. Now I can't  work with my application. I am trying to fix tomorrow .